# Why don't I get a Gnome GUI when I install Red Hat?

Tags: rhel, gnome, system-installation

I'm trying to install Red Hat on my Windows system but Im facing a problem. I get only one option during installation which is "Minimal" and even if I check Gnome desktop in customize options, I only get the command line after installation completes. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using a USB stick to install. Also another stange thing is that I get many options alongside Minimal when installing in Virtualbox - like Desktop, Server, etc.

Comment: I want to install the Dekstop version, not the server version.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this issue because, You have not selected following Package Groups:

> "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" "Fonts"

You can find [this article](http://www.jbmurphy.com/2011/12/01/how-to-add-gnome-to-centos-6-minimal-install/) for better guidance. one option is to reinstall again and choose these group of packages
**OR**
Install it through `yum` as shown in following command:
`yum groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" "Fonts"`
You can configure your local yum server by using instructions in [this](http://ostechnix.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/setup-local-yum-server-in-centos-6-x-rhel-6-x-scientific-linux-6-x/) link.

Comment: I did select those package groups you mentioned. But still all I got was the command line. Or did I miss something? Here is a list of all the items i selected:
1. Client management tolls
2.Debug 3. Directory Client 4. All the desktop options available except KDE 5. Network file system 6. Perl support 7. Printing Client

Comment: I think there should be a problem with your media (USB stick). Try with another one.

Answer (score 0):

You should select Desktop option, if you want it to be with default GUI (that is GNOME).

Have you tried to run `startx` or `init 5` ?